# Como utilizar diferentes bibliotecas javascript em uma mesma página?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando um slider tela cheia em uma pagina que estou criando, esse slide utiliza os seguintes estilos e funções JavaScript

**jQuery 3.2.1**:

```
var TIMEOUT = 6000;


var interval = setInterval(handleNext, TIMEOUT);

function handleNext() {

  var $radios = $('input[class*="slide-radio"]');
  var $activeRadio = $('input[class*="slide-radio"]:checked');

  var currentIndex = $activeRadio.index();
  var radiosLength = $radios.length;

  $radios
    .attr('checked', false);


  if (currentIndex >= radiosLength - 1) {

    $radios
      .first()
      .attr('checked', true);

  } else {

    $activeRadio
      .next('input[class*="slide-radio"]')
      .attr('checked', true);

  }

}
```

Quero adicionar a pagina um menu toogle off-canvas que utiliza esses estilos e funções do JavaScript

**jQuery 2.2.4**:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   $(".btn-nav").on("click tap", function() {
     $(".nav-container").toggleClass("showNav hideNav").removeClass("hidden");
     $(this).toggleClass("animated");
   });
 });
```

Os dois codigos entram em conflito quando usados em conjunto, já tentei deixar apenas uma biblioteca e se retiro uma não funciona a outra.

Tentei o método sem conflito e não funcionou, ao menos não consegui fazer funcionar.

Desculpe a ingenuidade, sou novo com programação.

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Rapaz, por favor, reformula sua pergunta, não consegui entender...

Comment: Luis, poste o trecho do código com inclusão das bibliotecas em seu html e tente simplificar a sua pergunta. Torne-a mais objetiva.

Comment: Olá Luis, tens a certeza que precisas da versão mais antiga? Já testaste usar só a versão 3?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta com os codigos

Comment: ja tentei usar apenas a versão 3.0 não funcionou, funcionas apenas um dos elementos, no caso o slider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está errado usando o método `.load` (que não serve para esse propósito) em:

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

Você quer criar os eventos quando a página terminar de ser carregada, então deveria usar:

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
```

Analisando seu código, não identifiquei nenhum conflito de versões, apenas esse erro citado do qual você está supondo ser conflito no jQuery. Faça a correção e seu código deve voltar a funcionar com qualquer das versões, mas sugiro usar a mais recente, `3.2.1`.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou. Entendi, nao existe conflito nos codigos o que estava errado era que um evento estava sendo chamado da forma errada, quando era pra ser chamado apos a página ser carregada, obrigado de novo, paz.

Comment: @LuisRodrigues Legal! Fico contente. Se puder, é importante marcar ✓ na resposta. Abs!

Comment: marcado obrigado